# How to increment for loop with NSMutable array in Xcode? (beacon.rssi)

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, ibeacon

I am trying to increment an array to add every value of beacon.rssi (not just when there is a change but every value even if it is the same as the previous result). Not sure what I am doing wrong. Console reports 1 value (most current) value of beacon.rssi but not previous values. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
//FOR loop storing values of beacon.rssi
for (int x=0; x<50;x++)
{
    rssiArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
    //rssiArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"%",@"2", nil];
    //Here I want to add the value of x to 'myholdingArray'
    //everytime x increments.

    // add as NSString
    //[rssiArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", x]];

    // or add as NSNumber
    [rssiArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:beacon.rssi]];
}

//Send array to console
NSLog (@"%@", [self rssiArray]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the array before the loop:

```
rssiArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++) {
    [rssiArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", x]];
    //[rssiArray addObject:@(beacon.rssi)];
}

//Send array to console
NSLog (@"%@", [self rssiArray]);
```

Also note the use of modern syntax.